# Want to apply machine learning algorithm to analysis of complex data

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, statistics

I am a currently looking at one of my tasks at work and I am considering some certain ideas and new approaches in order to solve it, so I really hope that I can get help from the experts in the field:-).

I am currently performing analysis of a complex data-set of historical data, which represents the relation between cost of building an offshore platform vs discovered resources for the current field(alternatively mean of the annual production can be used). Each data point has a set of parameters such as geographical origin, type of the main hydrocarbon, water depth, distance to the nearest infrastructure, type of platform and etc(a total of 10 parameters).
The idea is to construct a trend line, which could be used to predict costs of the future fields, given that production/resources of the latter are always reported.

An overall trend is such that costs are increasing if resources/production increase. So some linearity can be easily observed in the model, however, simple linear regression is too dummy in this case, given that we have a lot of different information given in the data-set.

I did my Master's degree in applied mathematics with specialization in numerical methods and PDEs, but what I am facing now is a pretty common statistical industry-related problem. I also assume that this task is a perfect candidate to be resolved by applying algorithms of machine learning, given that more and more data points will continuously be added and the curve/trend line could be used to further predict costs of future fields, knowing their production/resources and nature(parameters). However, I am totally new to this field, so any comment, information etc. from you would be highly appreciated:-)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. first - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - you should have a specific question to get a specific answer, this question may get closed as it is could get opinion based. Though we will try to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is IMHO very broad and not really specific, so you may get broad an not specific answer.

I believe you have a nice use case for machine learning implementation. Good work.

I'd recommend to get some "how-to" resources which are very practical and pragmatic. I really enjoyed [this ML course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/welcome) and it could point you where to start and how to proceed along hands-on approach, such as dividing data to learning, test and cross-validation sets, normalization, regularization, derived features,... etc.

Generally - you've already found that your problem looks like a supervised machine learning with multiple features. Linear regression may not fully work (as you pointed out), you can try to build more complex model, yet not overcomplicated. I'd start with polynomial model with regularized parameters and as well see if some derived features wouldn't be more fitting.

But it's only you who can see how your data look like and what could be starting model :) Good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I completely agree that the question is to broad, and I was not expecting to get any precise answer on it. Just wanted someone to point me the right way. And I think stack overflow is just the best place where I can get that kind of advice. I will definitely enroll myself to the course at course era! So again, thanks a lot for your comment